# Excluding header in conditional formatting function which is using TODAY()

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, header, conditional-formatting

My formula is the following one, I want the cell green if cell value is not "" and it's greater than today.

```
=AND(F1<>"";F1>=TODAY())
```

The thing is it applies to the whole column `=$F:$F`, and I have a header with text, which is filled with green.

I know I can execute the formula beginning at the first date value, but is there any way to exclude text values to this formula, or maybe some `IFNUMBER`, if exist?

Comment: check `ISNUMBER` and combine it with your formula. Or use and extra condition, something like `=AND(F1<>"";F1>=TODAY();ROW(F1)>1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(F1);F1>=TODAY())
```

Answer (score 3):

check `ISNUMBER` and combine it with your formula.

Or use and extra condition, something like `=AND(F1<>"";F1>=TODAY();ROW(F1)<>1)`

Exclude row 1 (if row 1 is the header row, ofc)